# HttpPostedFileBase.SaveAs() method keeps the fileopen?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm using the following method to save the uploaded file in an ASP.Net MVC application:

```
public static void SaveFile(HttpPostedFileBase file, string relativePath)
{
    string absolutePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(relativePath);            
    file.SaveAs(absolutePath);
}
```

and I use the following method to delete the file:

```
public static bool DeleteFile(string relativePath)
{
    string absolutePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(relativePath);
    if (File.Exists(absolutePath))
    {
        File.Delete(absolutePath)                
        return true;                            
    }
    return false;
}
```

When I try to delete a file immediately after uploading it, it can not be deleted. `File.Delete(absolutePath)` locks. After restarting iisexpress it successfully deletes the file. I used `Process Explorer` to check if the file is open in any other application. It was open in iisexpress. Does `HttpPostedFileBase.SaveAs()` method keeps the file open?

**Edit**
I call these methods through ajax call.

Comment: - why you save file if u want to delete file immediately ??
and I don't think  `File.SaveAs`  method open file  its just save your file stream  to your drive



----Did you make sure you do not have the file in temp open somewhere else?

Comment: It's an image gallery. Maybe a user upload a wrong image, so he wants to delete it. I don't open file in any other part of code. I just return the file path to view the uploaded file.

Comment: I'm really really sorry for asking this question. As @Anant Dabhi mentioned HttpPostedFileBase.SaveAs() does not open the file. The file was open with another service that I did not considered when debugging.

Comment: its happens many times bro..  experience makes u perfect ... :)